# Is there any logic possible to rename firebase upload file in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to rename my uploaded files using some reGex before I store them in the firebase storage.

As much as I know now, firebase file metadata doesn't allow that. I was wondering if there is anyway possible to do that. I am using angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload a file to Firebase Storage, you explicitly specify the name that the file gets. From the [documentation on uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files):

```
// Create a root reference
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
var mountainsRef = storageRef.child('mountains.jpg');
```

Now it doesn't matter what file you upload, it will be named `mountains.jpg` in Firebase Storage. For example:

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API
mountainsRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Property         Type      Writable
bucket           string    NO
generation       string    NO
metageneration   string    NO
fullPath         string    NO
name             string    NO
```

Unfortunately not, name is not editable property: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: but it is the full answer

Comment: Hi Sergii Syrkin, at the time of my comment just link was their, its edited after my comment.